# Android Azure Mobile Services Google auth

Tags: android, azure, authentication, azure-mobile-services

The Azure MobileServiceClient in built authenticator shows a webview when trying to log in using an Android device. Is there a way such that it can be used to call the Play Services Login Dialog box and log in through there? I was following the tutorial given [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-users/#add-authentication-to-the-app).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use a "Client Directed Flow", assuming the Google Play Services Login Dialog produces a standard Google token and you know the Client ID of the Google App.

1) [Configure Azure Authentication / Authorization for Google](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication/)

2) Configure your app to use the [Google Play Services Login Dialog] (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)

3) Obtain the Google token (from GoogleAuthUtil.getToken)

4) Use the google token to do a client-directed login using the Azure Mobile Apps Android SDK:

```
ListenableFuture<MobileServiceUser> mLogin = mClient.login(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google, theGoogleToken);
```

There should not be another dialog produced, but you will get the ZUMO-TOKEN back as described in the [Server Flow](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-users/#add-authentication-to-the-app)