# Azure mobile Apps Authentication: Allow users choose provider

Tags: android, facebook, azure, authentication, azure-mobile-services

I'm developing a small android application where users needs to login. i dont wanna implement a full login system because i think it's no really necessary for this application, i just wan't allow users to login in my application using their Facebook or google accounts, and then store their basic profile info in azure database. the access to the database is restricted to "authenticated users only", at this point i have only added the Facebook Login button and can read users data, but when i need to store this information in the database i'm going to need authenticate in the azure service, i wan't to use the users session data (Facebook and Google) to login into azure. how can i do it?. I dont want to force users to login twice in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this documentation for information on how to add Google and Facebook authentication to your mobile app: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-users/. When a user logs in, your app backend can easily get their user data and make secured calls to your Azure database on behalf of the logged-in user.

Comment: Hi, i have already tested the "Add authentication to your Android app" but this is opening a second "login screen" and not using the Default Facebook App to do the login.

Comment: Yes, that is the case when you use the server-directed login flow for App Service. Instead, you want to use the client-directed flow, which allows you to use the Google tokens you got in the initial login to do a silent login with the App Service backend in Azure. Take a look at this answer here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35621187/2069